# Windows SDK for production version of application

Tags: visual-studio

I currently faced an issue with `Windows SDK`. After developing application for some time I managed to get production, stable version. I tried to install it on my server and it started to throw exception with missing dlls.

I debugged and analyzed it and I discovered that missing `Windows SDK` is an issue. I know that it is installed with `VisualStudio`. How should I install it on production machines where I don't want to have `VisualStudio`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify a language, but I assume C++. Please start by changing your project to Release mode before building. This should link against the redistributable versions of the C++ runtime library. If that doesn't fix it, you may need to install the proper runtime on the destination machine:

- [Visual C++ 2013 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)
- [Visual C++ 2010 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)